# Bootstrap carousel slide controls not responding

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I have a rotating carousel with the bootstrap indicators at the bottom which are supposed to indicate which slide is visible. The white circles, however, aren't clickable, nor do they indicate which slide is actually visible.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu-button-container">
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>  
<figure>
    <div class="image-slide active" id="image-1">
        <div class="main-image-options-box">
            <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Brexit: Whats Next?</div>
            <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">Since the UK voted for the UK to leave te European Union, whhat happen next to your investments, & what can you do to pretect your returns?</div>
            <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-slide" id="image-2">
        <div class="main-image-options-box">
            <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Ready-made portfolios</div>
            <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">Our ready-made portfolios are designed to capture market directions by adjusting sensative to non-sensative securites to make the most of market swings</div>
            <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">This is another caption.</div>
            <a href="#">Read more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-slide" id="image-3">
        <div class="main-image-options-box">
            <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Corporate pensions</div>
            <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">Corporate pensions ae suffering. Find out how we can help you start your own private pension. Get set up for the coming years ahead.</div>
            <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-slide" id="image-4">
        <div class="main-image-options-box">
            <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Losing cash on your ISA?</div>
            <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">With the recent cut in the Bank of England base rate, now staing at .25%, find out how your ISA ivestments will react.</div>
            <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</figure>
</div>
<div id="menu-cascading-image-button-container">
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
    <div class="triangle" id="tri-1"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="far-left" data- target="#slider" data-slide-to="0">
        <div class="inner-text-box" id="default-button">Ready made portfolios<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
    <div class="triangle" id="tri-2"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-left" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Apply for an ISA Account<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
<div class="triangle" id="tri-3"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-right" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Current Accounts<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
<div class="triangle" id="tri-4"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" data-target="'slider" data-slide-to="4">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Savings Accountss<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
 .carousel-indicators li {
  border: solid;
 }
 .main-image-options-box
 {
  padding-left:50px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu-button-container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="simple-carousel">
   <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
     <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li class="active" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item">
       <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Brexit: Whats Next?</div>
       <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">Since the UK voted for the UK to leave te European Union, whhat happen next to your investments, & what can you do to pretect your returns?</div>
       <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Ready-made portfolios</div>
      <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">Our ready-made portfolios are designed to capture market directions by adjusting sensative to non-sensative securites to make the most of market swings</div>
      <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">This is another caption.</div>
      <a href="#">Read more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     </div>
     <div class="item active">
      <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Corporate pensions</div>
      <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">Corporate pensions ae suffering. Find out how we can help you start your own private pension. Get set up for the coming years ahead.</div>
      <a href="#" style="margin-left:100px;">Find out more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="main-image-options-box">
       <div class="main-image-options-box-header">Losing cash on your ISA?</div>
       <div class="main-image-options-box-caption">With the recent cut in the Bank of England base rate, now staing at .25%, find out how your ISA ivestments will react.</div>
       <a href="#">Find out more<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#carousel-example-generic" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a><a href="#carousel-example-generic" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="menu-cascading-image-button-container">
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
    <div class="triangle" id="tri-1"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="far-left" data- target="#slider" data-slide-to="0">
        <div class="inner-text-box" id="default-button">Ready made portfolios<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
    <div class="triangle" id="tri-2"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-left" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Apply for an ISA Account<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
<div class="triangle" id="tri-3"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" id="center-right" data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Current Accounts<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-cascading-image-button-arrow-container">
<div class="triangle" id="tri-4"></div>
    <div class="menu-cascading-image-button" data-target="'slider" data-slide-to="4">
        <div class="inner-text-box">Savings Accountss<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which name (i.e. "menu-button-container" or "col-md-6") do you edit to adjust the dimensions of the carousel? Mines 1000px by 600px;

I've voted your answer upwards as well :)

Comment: I have adjusted the size of container with class col-md-6, you can read more about bootstrap responsive classes go to this link http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid or you can add custom css class with your dimensions 1000px or 600px